# How to split dataframe according sub ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 3 columns containing image data set.1st column name 'ID' where ID represent patient id, 2nd and 3rd columns represent side and label of the data set respectively.I would like to split this dataframe in to test and train set according to patient ID in where patient Id wouldn't be repeat in both set.I mean the train ID would not present in the test set. Using this below code

```
# Defining a function for spliting dataframe into train and test
df_Datacopy = df_Data.copy() # copy the df

#df_Datacopy= df_Datacopy.sort_values(by=['ID'])
df_Datacopy = df_Datacopy.sample(frac=1)

train_df = df_Datacopy.sample(frac=0.80, random_state=0) # train spliting size 80%

# sorted according to ID
train_df= train_df.sort_values(by=['ID'])

# test split and by removing train index
test_df = df_Datacopy.drop(train_df.index)

# sorted according to ID
test_df= test_df.sort_values(by=['ID'])

u1 = np.unique(train_df['ID'])
u2 = np.unique(test_df['ID'])
print(set(u1).union(set(u2)))
```

I tried to split the test and train set,but the problem is the i seen that  some ID present in both test and train set.It would be a great help for me if i get some help including code example.

Comment: Each id have about the same amount of rows? or it is totally unbalanced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple Python Lists Approach

So I would recommend using simple python lists for this as the preferred and simpler approach.Since you started with pandas I'll provide a way to use pandas methods to achieve something similar but with a possible worse outcome.

```
whole_dataset_list =df_copy.to_numpy().tolist()
patientid_list =df['ID'].to_numpy().tolist()
patientid_set =list(set(patientid_list))

import random as rand
rand.shuffle(patientid_set)

#Change the numbers as to represent a 80% slice of your dataset/10/10 respectively
train_set_by_patientID = patientid_set[0:800] # 80 
val_set_by_patientID = patientid_set[800:900] # 10
test_set_by_patientID = patientid_set[1000:] # 10
```

After splitting these lists you can use them to obtain the final train/test/val splits as such.

```
for i in range(len(wholeDataset_list)):
    curr_pt_id = wholeDataset_list[i]
    if(curr_pt_id in train_set_by_patientID):
        train_set.append(wholeDataset_list[i])
    elif(curr_pt_id in val_set_by_patientID):
        val_set.append(wholeDataset_list[i])
    elif(curr_pt_id in test_set_by_patientID):
        test_set.append(wholeDataset_list[i])
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Whole dataset does not contain given i ")
```

Finally you can come back to a dataframe if you want as such:

```
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_set, columns=df_copy.columns)
val_df = pd.DataFrame(val_set, columns=df_copy.columns)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_set, columns=df_copy.columns)
```

## Second Option using Pandas Only:

Here sop_uid is a unique index. I am using a train/val/test split instead of a train/test split but that can be changed easily.

```
dff.sort_values(by="patient_id", axis=0, inplace=True)
count_study = dff.groupby_agg(by = 'patient_id', agg='count', agg_column_name='sop_uid', new_column_name="count_instances")
df_Datacopy = dict_dff

train_df = df_Datacopy.sample(frac=0.90, weights='count_study', random_state=0) # train spliting size 90%
train_df= train_df.sort_values(by=['count_instances'], ascending = False)
# test split and by removing train index
test_df = df_Datacopy.drop(train_df.index)
# sorted according to count_study
test_df= test_df.sort_values(by=['count_instances'], ascending = False)
#Sample 
train_df = train_df.sample(frac=0.89, weights='count_study', random_state=0) # train spliting size 80%
train_df= train_df.sort_values(by=['count_instances'], ascending = False)

val_df = df_Datacopy.drop(train_df.index.append(test_df.index))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a boolean mask to filter the dataset.
If you want to split 50/50 maybe checking if ID is even or uneven might work.

Since you didnt provide any sample data or furter detail on which citeria to split i suggest

```
train_df= df[df.ID % 2 == 0]
test_df = df[df.ID % 2 != 0]
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?
If not maybe provide more information on what result you want.

Comment: ID SIDE V00XRKL
9000099 1 2
9000099 2 3
9000296 1 2
9000296 2 3
My dataset look like above.Suppose i would like to keep both 9000099 ID in the train set that would not be present in the test set.@ArsenieBoca